# Hammer.js events with Marionette.js doesn't work

Tags: requirejs, marionette, backbone-events, hammer.js

I'm trying to use Hammer.js with Backbone , Marionette and Require.js

When i initialize events , the event is not fired .

I use Hammer.js and jQuery.hammer extension

I would like to do something like that :

*edit :*

```
events: {
    "tap .menu ": " handleTap "
},

handleTape: function(){
    console.log("Hammer time!");
},

onRender: function () {
    // Instantiate Hammer
    $ This el.hammer().
}
```

To reach this goal , i include Hammer.js first , then jquery.hammer before Backbone and Marionette.js. There is no error in debug console, just my event is not detected

There is way to bind hammer's events without doing something like :

```js
onRender: function () {
    // Instantiate Hammer and bind tap event
    this.$el.hammer().bind('tap .menu', function () {
        console.log('Hammer Time!'
        }).
    }
```

Comment: This may be just a copy error but you bound `handleTap` in your `events` hash, while your view only has a property named `handleTape`

Comment: whoops ! Typing error when I created this post :) I modified it.